# Stuck on finding a closed formula for sequence, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am stuck on the following question:

The sequence 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 12...... can be generated by a closed formula. Find the formula.

I can see that the recurrence relation is $a_n = a_{n-3} + 2$

I also found this solution online which does seem to work, however, I cannot understand how to derive it.

(thank you to user75900, Find closed form for $1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9, 10, 10, \ldots$, URL (version: 2013-06-20): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/425141)

$\dfrac{2\sin(\frac23(n-1)\pi)}{3\sqrt3}+\dfrac{2n+1}3+5$

Could anyone help me understand how user75900 came to this closed formula.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'd start with $\{n^2\pmod 3\}=\{0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,\cdots\}$.  At least that gets you the right shape.

Comment: What is the characteristic equation for $a_n=a_{n-3}+2$ ?

Comment: What do you know about solving recurrence relations? Can you see why a trig function has come up?

Comment: You could use OEIS (https://oeis.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(n)$ be the formula for $(5,6,6,7,8,8,...)$.

Since $f$ is raised by $2$ for every $3$ numbers, a naive guess for $f$ would be
$$f(n)=5+\frac23n.$$

But this gives the following sequence
\begin{align*}
&(5,\,5+\tfrac23,\,5+\tfrac43,\,7\,,\,7+\tfrac23,7+\tfrac43,...)\\[.5em]
=\ &(5,\,6-\tfrac13,\,6+\tfrac13,\,7,\,7-\tfrac13,\,7+\tfrac13,...),
\end{align*}

which differs from the original sequence by $(0,\frac13,-\frac13,0,\frac13,-\frac13,...)$. Therefore, the correct formula should be $$f(n)=5+\frac23n+g(n)$$
where $g(n)$ is the formula for the periodic sequence $(0,\frac13,-\frac13,...)$. This means $g(n)$ is periodic with period $3$. Since a natural choice of periodic functions are trig functions ($\sin,\,\cos$), we can take the guess
$$g(n)=b\sin(an)$$
for some constants $a,b$. First we have $a=\frac{2\pi}3$ since the period is $3$, then it follows
$$b\sin\left(\frac{2n\pi}3\right)=\left\{\begin{matrix}\frac13,\ \text{if}\ \text{mod}(n,3)=1\\-\frac13,\ \text{if}\ \text{mod}(n,3)=2\end{matrix}\right..$$
This easily implies $b=\frac2{3\sqrt3}$. Hence, we have got the correct formula
$$f(n)=5+\frac23n+\frac2{3\sqrt3}\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n}3\right).$$

Comment: Thank you so much, we had not been taught how to apply trig in this way, now you walked me through it I understand and will be able to tackle more questions like this.

Comment: Glad this can help!